# Filter,group and divide 2D NSArray in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a 2D NSArray, and I want to filter,group and divide to separate 2D NSArray base on filter object key. So how I can do it ?

```
    NSMutableArray *totalRatings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A1", @"Device", @"2018-07-04 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"25.6", @"Temp", nil],
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A2", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"23.4", @"Temp", nil],
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A3", @"Device", @"2018-07-04 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"23.6", @"Temp", nil],
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A1", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"26.3", @"Temp", nil],
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A2", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"25.8", @"Temp", nil],
                                .........
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Device_n", @"Device", @"date_time_n", @"measure_time", @"25.8", @"Temp", nil],
                         nil];
```

CASE1: Filter, sort by "Measure_time" key. OUTPUT:

```
NSMutableArray separated_date_time_1 =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A1", @"Device", @"2018-07-04 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"25.6", @"Temp",nil
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A3", @"Device", @"2018-07-04 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"23.6", @"Temp", nil],
                                        nil],

NSMutableArray separated_date_time_2 =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A2", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"23.4", @"Temp", nil],
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A1", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"26.3", @"Temp", nil],
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A2", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"25.8", @"Temp", nil],
                                       nil],


NSMutableArray separated_date_time_n =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Device_n", @"Device", @"date_time_n", @"measure_time", @"25.8", @"Temp", nil],
                                      nil],
```

CASE2: Filter by Device, OUTPUT:

```
NSMutableArray separated_Device_A1 =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A1", @"Device", @"2018-07-04 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"25.6", @"Temp",nil
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A1", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"26.3", @"Temp", nil],
                                        nil],

  NSMutableArray separated_Device_A2 =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A2", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"23.4", @"Temp", nil],
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A2", @"Device", @"2018-07-05 16:09:22", @"measure_time", @"25.8", @"Temp", nil],
                                       nil],


   NSMutableArray separated_Device_A_n =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Device_n", @"Device", @"date_time_n", @"measure_time", @"25.8", @"Temp", nil],
                                      nil],
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but I would create a helper method that would group all data based on a given key - I am assuming that keys are of type `NSString` if not you will have to modify this a bit:

```
- (NSDictionary *)groupByKey:(NSString *)key data:(NSArray *)data {
NSMutableDictionary *groupedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dataDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSString *keyValue = dataDict[key];

        if (keyValue != nil) {
            NSMutableArray *objectsWithKey = groupedDictionary[keyValue];

            if (objectsWithKey == nil) {
                objectsWithKey = [NSMutableArray new];
            }

            [objectsWithKey addObject:dataDict];
            groupedDictionary[keyValue] = objectsWithKey;
        }
    }];

    return [groupedDictionary copy];
}
```

You can then use this like so:

```
NSDictionary *groupedByDevice = [self groupByKey:@"Device" data:totalRatings];
```

This will return to you all unique device names as keys, and values will be an array of objects with that device name:

```
{
A1 =     (
            {
        Device = A1;
        Temp = "25.6";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-04 16:09:22";
    },
            {
        Device = A1;
        Temp = "26.3";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-05 16:09:22";
    }
);
A2 =     (
            {
        Device = A2;
        Temp = "23.4";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-05 16:09:22";
    },
            {
        Device = A2;
        Temp = "25.8";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-05 16:09:22";
    }
);
A3 =     (
            {
        Device = A3;
        Temp = "23.6";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-04 16:09:22";
    }
);
}
```

Same as above just that `measure_time` is used to group:

```
NSDictionary *groupedByMeasure = [self groupByKey:@"measure_time" data:totalRatings];
```

with result being:

```
{
"2018-07-04 16:09:22" =     (
            {
        Device = A1;
        Temp = "25.6";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-04 16:09:22";
    },
            {
        Device = A3;
        Temp = "23.6";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-04 16:09:22";
    }
);
"2018-07-05 16:09:22" =     (
            {
        Device = A2;
        Temp = "23.4";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-05 16:09:22";
    },
            {
        Device = A1;
        Temp = "26.3";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-05 16:09:22";
    },
            {
        Device = A2;
        Temp = "25.8";
        "measure_time" = "2018-07-05 16:09:22";
    }
);
}
```